# MongoDb (k8s pod) is failing due to Operation is not permitted

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I'm running a mongoDB (5.0.12) instance as a kubernetes pod. Suddenly the pod is failing and I need some help to understand the logs:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-13T18:39:51.104+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"AuthorizationManager-1","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":1,"message":"[1663094391:104664][1:0x7fc5224cc700], file:index-9--3195476868760592993.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/index-9--3195476868760592993.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-13T18:39:51.104+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":50882,   "ctx":"AuthorizationManager-1","msg":"Failed to open WiredTiger cursor. This may be due to data corruption","attr":{"uri":"table:index-9--3195476868760592993","config":"overwrite=false","error":{"code":8,"codeName":"UnknownError","errmsg":"1: Operation not permitted"},"message":"Please read the documentation for starting MongoDB with --repair here: http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-13T18:39:51.104+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"AuthorizationManager-1","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":50882,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp","line":109}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-13T18:39:51.104+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"AuthorizationManager-1","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

So why is there `operation is not permitted`? I already run `mongod --repair`, but the error still occurs.

This is how the pod is deployed:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      hostname: mongodb
      # securityContext:
      #   runAsUser: 999
      #   runAsGroup: 3000
      #   fsGroup: 2000
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: data
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo:5.0.12
          args: ["--auth", "--dbpath", "/data/db"]
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data/db
              name: data
          # securityContext:
          #   allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

*Update*

The PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

Comment: Check the permissions are correct. It could be an selinux issue, try below :

setenforce 0

 
After this  if server starts , If the server starts , use semanage to set the context to the mongo data folder.

Comment: This doc might help [https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/)

Comment: can you please share your pvc manifest file  ?

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar I have updated the post. Is this, what you meant?

Comment: yes. Let me check

Comment: Is there any other restrictions ? I am not able to reproduce the issue for me the pod is working fine

Comment: Are you using minikube by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking the permissions for that file before execution:

```
ls -l
```

then using **chmod** you can try changing the permission and then try executing it.

OR

You can refer here, this might help you:

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

Comment: I don't understand which values I have to use for the security context. That's why this part is commented out in my pod deployment file.

Comment: You can refer these sections:
1. Set the security context for a Pod
2. Set the security context for a Container

Let me know if it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this security context is working.

```yaml
name: app-mongo
image: mongo:4.4.6
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 999
```

Because the MongoDB Dockerfile is using the user 999 : https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/4.4/Dockerfile

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look at setting the umask on the directory:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

That will ensure new files in the directory are created with the specified permissions/ownerships.